# Entity Framework using Sub Select not INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the below classes such as

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Int32 TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TeamFeed> TeamFeeds { get; set; }
}

public class TeamFeed
{       
    public Int32 TeamFeedId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I have `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` and `ProxyCreationEnabled = false`

When I do

```
var team = db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamId == 1).Include(x=>x.TeamFeeds);
```

The SQL generated by EF looks like:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[TeamFeedId] AS [TeamFeedId], 
[Project1].[TeamId1] AS [TeamId1], 
[Project1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled], 
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description],  
    [Extent2].[TeamFeedId] AS [TeamFeedId], 
    [Extent2].[TeamId] AS [TeamId1], 
    [Extent2].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled],  
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[TeamFeedId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Teams] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TeamFeeds] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TeamId] = [Extent2].[TeamId]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[TeamId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[TeamId] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

I don't understand why it hasn't used SQL that I would use and created a long winded SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
* --use all just for clarity in the example
FROM TEAMS T

INNER JOIN TEAMFEEDS TF
ON T.TEAMID = TF.TEAMID

ORDER BY 
T.TEAMID
```

I'm new to EF so it may be I'm not be understanding something.

Thanks

Comment: Entity Framework often creates more verbose queries, but they typically perform just as well (sometimes even better) than a shorter one.  Of course, EF often is more conservative, and generates code that adresses edge cases you may not care about.  Also, EF does what you ask it to do, not necessarily what you meant it to do, so sometimes it creates bad code because it's trying to do exactly what you told it to do, but can't without doing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your query using `INNER JOIN` won't return anything, when Team with `TeamID = 1` has no feeds. `LEFT JOIN` has to be used here, and that's what EF did in ineer `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM  [dbo].[Teams] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TeamFeeds] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TeamId] = [Extent2].[TeamId]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[TeamId]
```

Following *scary* line is just to let EF know, if left site of the `JOIN` was specified - it returns `0` if Team has no Feeds and `1` if at lease one Feed was found.

```
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[TeamFeedId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
```

And outer `SELECT` statement just maps DataBase columns names to EF model properties names and does `ORDER BY`.

Hope it's enough of explenation why EF generated such *a long winded SQL statement*. Or rather why this statement only looks scary, but really is not much more then your simple `SELECT * FROM Teams JOIN Feeds`.